# Setting the 'first' class attribute for navigation in MasterPage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have my master page that has navigation:

```
                 <ul>
                    <li class="first"><a title="Home" href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a title="Download" href="Download.aspx">Download</a></li>
                    <li><a title="Buy Coins" href="Store.aspx">Buy Coins</a></li>
                    <li><a title="Support" href="Support.aspx">Support</a></li>
                </ul>
```

The problem is I can't figure out how I could set the class="first" attribute based on where the user is. Does .NET have a way to do this? I could copy paste the nav to all my pages but that just seems wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most straightforward way I can think of is just to check the type of the page:

```
<li class="<%= (Page is Home) ? "first" : "" %>"><a title="Home" href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class="<%= (Page is Download) ? "first" : "" %>"><a title="Download" href="/">Download</a></li>
```

Comment: I am getting type errors, it can't find the type Download, Support etc and the classes are indeed named this way.

Comment: Those types would be the names of the classes representing your pages. Usually when you create `Home.aspx`, you get three files: `Home.aspx`, `Home.aspx.cs`, and `Home.aspx.designer.cs`. The .cs file is `public class Home : Page`. So when you say `Page is Home`, "Home" represents the class name for the page. If you're in a different namespace, or if you named your class something different, you'd have to make the appropriate change, or add the <%@ Import Namespace="whatever" %> to the top of the page.